# How can I process http responses with XSLT in Apache webserver?

Tags: apache2, xslt

I have a PHP application that I want to also publish with a different look and feel. We've chosen to do that using XSLT. That way we don't have to touch the PHP application and run risk introducing instability in the original. That's important since we're close to production.

I've looked into ways of doing XSLT processing in Apache webserver. And it seems that the only available [xslt module](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/web/libapache2-modxslt) hasn't been updated since 2005. I was hoping to use an xslt mod in a filter chain to accomplish what I want. But an unsupported module won't do.
Another option I can think of is to do the XSLT processing using a servletfilter in a java application server. It seems rather roundabout to have an http request arrive at apache webserver, be forwarded to a java application server to be forwarded back to the apache webserver to do the PHP processing, and the reverse way back for the response...

So my question is: Is there a way to do XSLT processing in apache webserver? Is there another way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've also tried out xslt-filter. That has seen some activity in 2008 but has died out since.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a good way to do that in apache. You could do it with PHP using [its XSL(T) module](http://php.net/xsl), though.